# Concentric circles of radii 1, 2, 3, ...upto 100 are drawn.

Tags: geometry, circles

Concentric circles radii $1, 2, 3, \ldots , 100$ are drawn. The interior of the smallest circle is colored red and the annular regions are colored alternately green and red, so that no two adjacent regions are the same color. The total area of the green regions divided by the area of the largest circle is

- $\frac12$
- $\frac{51}{100}$
- $\frac{101}{200}$
- $\frac{50}{101}$
- none of the foregoing

Comment: Have you tried calculating the areas? As multiples of $\pi$? With this type of problems the number of circles is just a parameter (but it may be essential that it is even!). Therefore you should do a bit of work yourself, and calculate the red/green areas, when the number of circles is 2,4,6 or 8. You may even see a pattern emerging! If you do that, and include the results into your question, then others see that you are trying. Consequently they will be more willing to help you. Otherwise they will be less willing, as it may sound that you want somebody else to do your homework.

Comment: What's the source? What's the interest? What are your thoughts on the problem, beyond thinking you could copy-paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Drawing a diagram, you'll come up with the quantity:
$$ \begin{align*}
&\dfrac{(\pi\cdot2^2-\pi\cdot1^2) + (\pi\cdot4^2-\pi\cdot3^2) + \ldots + (\pi\cdot100^2-\pi\cdot99^2)}{\pi \cdot 100^2} \\
&= \dfrac{(2^2-1^2) + (4^2-3^2) + \ldots + (100^2-99^2)}{100^2}\\
&= \dfrac{(2-1)(2+1) + (4-3)(4+3) + \ldots + (100-99)(100+99)}{100^2}\\
&= \dfrac{3 + 7 + \ldots + 199}{100^2}\\
\end{align*}$$
where the second to last step involved factoring several differences of squares. It remains to figure out the sum of an arithmetic series of $50$ terms whose first term is $3$, common difference is $4$, and last term is $199$. Hopefully you can finish the rest off on your own.

Comment: Well, it's nice that you left *something* for OP to do.